# Indexes of data bits in PC

Tags: digital-logic

I've a question related to digital logic which is:
Why if I have 2^n possibilities for n bits then the indexes of the bits itself are from [0:2^n -1 ]? I'm not understanding why we must initialize the indexes from zero... Who said that bits are primarily indexed at first by zero? Why are we not initializing bit indexes from 2 or any other number? Sound weird for me. Any illustration please? Is that an axiom (starting from index zero till 2^n -1) that PC works with?

Comment: The best way to understand is to sit down and design a memory system that doesn't start at zero (or some binary multiple of the memory unit size.) You will have zero questions once you try your hands at doing it differently.

Answer (score 2):

Think of their binary weights. The value of each bit is \$ 2^b \$ where \$ b \$ is the bit number. Thus the least significant bit is worth \$ 2^0 = 1 \$ and the MSB is worth \$ 2^{n-1} \$.

- \$ 2^0 = 1 \$
- \$ 2^1 = 2 \$
- \$ 2^2 = 4 \$
- etc.

You can also think of if as an offset from the least significant bit. LSB has an offset of 0 and MSB has an offset of *n - 1*.

---

Here's a 4-bit binary number sequence with decimal representations:

```
Bit #  3 2 1 0  |
Weight 8 4 2 1  | Decimal
----------------+--------
       0 0 0 0  |  0
       0 0 0 1  |  1
       0 0 1 0  |  2
       0 0 1 1  |  3
       0 1 0 0  |  4
       0 1 0 1  |  5
       ....
       1 1 1 0  | 14
       1 1 1 1  | 15
```

Look at binary value for decimal 14, '1110'. To convert to decimal we just add the bits that are on, bits 3, 2 and 1 as follows: \$ 1110_2 = 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 = 8 + 4 + 2 = 14_{10}\$.

This is the logical way to do this. If we used a system starting at 1 then the converstion would be \$ 1110_2 = 2^{4-1} + 2^{3-1} + 2^{2-1} = 8 + 4 + 2 = 14_{10}\$. This would be a pain.

---

Decimal notation

In our decimal notation we do the same thing. A three-digit number, say 987, is made up of 100s, 10s and units. It's value is \$ 9 \times 10^2 + 8 \times 10^1 + 7 \times 10^0 \$. Again, the least significant digit has an index of 0.

Comment: So I understand that science didn't start indexes of bits from 0 just like that ...... , he started it from zero because zero is counted in Computer's computing in other words 2^0 is 1 so it worth ! as a result we should start index from zero till ... but also why determined to start from 0 not from -1? 2^-1 is also worth .. so? I'm getting more and more confused why we should start indexes of bit from zero?!! why should I start from offset 0 at least significant bit and not from offset -1 and say it's least significant bit? 2^-1 also worth!

Comment: Ryan, please write in proper sentences without "..." so that we can understand what you are saying. I will edit my answer if you let us know how much you understand about binary numbers. \$ 2^{-1} = \frac {1}{2} \$ so that is no use in integer maths.

Comment: Sorry about that way of writing, I'm still confused about why we are starting from zero specifically ? not from 1? I mean 32 bits we can say it's indexed by [1-32] which will have 32 bits but it's wrong (idk why) and we should say [0:31] , my question to remember it and not just save it as a parrot, why we are starting from 0 : 31 and not from 1:32 ? any suitable illustration to convince me please?! thanks in advance very much.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: It might help if you edit your question to show how you would convert from binary to decimal in your scheme on a 1-based offset. I think that by the time you're finished you will understand that 0-based offset is intuitive and logical and simple.

Comment: People find it easy that a_i has a logical weight of 2^i. It simplify many formulas, algorithms, etc. Any other numbering would not have this property. That's the reason of this numbering.